# Snowflake Weird Results - Unit Conversion?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using snowflake, and my table has 3 columns:

- height
- width
- depth

These are all stored as VARCHAR data types.

The values themselves are, 24.0000, 18.0000, and 18.0000.

When I run a query like this,

```
SELECT height * width * depth as total_volume,
total_volume * 0.8 as eighty_percent_volume
FROM table
```

The answer I get is: `3.6`

I expect the answer to be `6220.8`

Through troubleshooting, I discovered that the "wrong" answer is always implicitly divided by `1728` which just happens to be the unit conversion of cubic feet to cubic inches.

How or why in the world is snowflake converting the answer to feet for me?

What's strange, is if I rewrite the SQL like this,

```
SELECT height * width * depth as total_volume,
height * width * depth * 0.8 as eighty_percent_volume
FROM table
```

I get the correct answer. So how or why does referring to the alias make a difference?

Comment: I get the correct answer using both of your SQL statements. Can you provide a reproducible script that gets the wrong answer?

Comment: @GregPavlik No, it is specific to this table for some reason. I have also tried to recreate it as well with a script that would run on a different database, but theres something with this table or this snowflake account that is causing the issue. Another clue I've found is that the ALIAS name matters. If I rename total_volume to a different alias, it works fine. Is it possible that I could be using some sort of secret conversion function as my alias name and not know it? I've never heard of this functionality

Comment: Do you happen to have a column in that table with a name of "total_volume"? Maybe someone created it, and the actual column name would supersede an alias.

Comment: @Josh, there is no function in Snowflake with that name, and you can in most cases use function names as identifiers (though I don't recommend it). You can see a list of all functions using the `show functions` command.

Comment: Thanks Greg, will check that out. Also Isolated, that's a great idea it might be something like that. Will check and post an update

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GregPavlik and @Isolated for helping track this down.

The root cause was a silly mistake, as is often the case.

Here's an explanation in case someone uncovers this post in desperation.

If you have a query, like:

```
SELECT A.col1,
  A.col2,
  A.col3,
  1337 AS col1
FROM table
```

You will actually return two `col1`. I would have assumed that an error would occur in that case, but apparently not.

Therefore if you then attempt to use that alias like,

```
SELECT 
  A.col2,
  A.col3,
  1337 AS col1,
  col1 + 1337
FROM table
```

This will refer to the actual column in the table `col1` and not the alias that you created.

In my case, this view had already a calculated column that calculated the total_volume, and I used the existing name as my alias, and the column happened to be pre-converted from inches to feet, which was an extra source of confusion when I saw the strange result.

This is all very simple now that it's discovered, but was very confusing! Thanks for all the help.

TL-DR; Be careful with Alias names!

Comment: The alias will be use if there is no table, but as you have found row column names take priority. This can also bit you in recursive cte’s where you get the last output of this table and the current value. The work around is to use a alias on the cte and a different alias for the row